# Modelling independent ordinal variable

Tags: modeling, ordinal-data, predictor

When we have nominal independent variables in Regression we model them by using binary dummies with levels equal to the levels of the nominal variable minus 1. I prefer the base to be zeros and not minus 1. How can I mathematically model an ordinal independent variable to maintain the order?

Thanks in advance,

Andreas

Answer (score 1):

The only approaches I've seen that respect the ordinal nature of such a predictor are

- isotonic regression which forces the relationship between X and Y to be monotonic in X.  I'm not clear if this works in the context of also adjusting for other variables.
- Bayesian shrinkage priors where you model X as categorical with $k-1$ indicators for $k$ levels but connect the $k-1$ effects to shrink the differences between the parameter values.  This is done automatically for ordinal predictors in the R `brms` package `brm` function.

Comment: How do statistical software e. G. Sas do it?

Comment: R has these capabilities.   I doubt SAS has very much.